# Unable to align time stamps in custom chat template

Tags: liveagent

Looks like Salesforce renders these differently in standard implementation, therefore my CSS class is not able to align operator and client timestamps to each side.

Have a look at screenshots.

[image: Custom layout]

[image: Standard layout]

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself! Turns out there is a boolean [parameter](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_vf_liveagent_clientchatlog.htm) `combineMessagesText` on `liveAgent:clientChatLog` that groups em together.